# How to get the list of Applications that reference the library using weblogic command line reference?

Tags: deployment, weblogic

As I need to force stop all the applications references before un-deploying a library in the weblogic server.

How to get the list of applications in the "**Applications in that reference this library**" tab in library settings in the weblogic server using weblogic command line reference.

Hence I can stop only those applications instead of stopping all the applications.

Comment: actually you'll need to do a crossreference between serverRuntime().LibraryRuntimes and applicationRuntimes/{name}/libraryRuntimes/{name}/referencingRuntimes

Answer (score 0):

This information is available from LibraryRuntimeMBean.ReferencingRuntimes
Have a look to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In WLST, you can iterate the libraries and get the applications name.

```
serverRuntime()

listLibraries=cmo.getLibraryRuntimes()

for library in listLibraries :
   for referencingRuntime in library.getReferencingRuntimes() :
      print referencingRuntime.getName()
```